# Conceptual Model linking multiple tables by Year

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, snowflake-schema

This is maybe a very basic question, but I'm trying to model something, ideally with a start schema. I've provided some dummy data.

The first table just lists out "Scores" (not too important what this score represents) for each country by year.

The second table just has the score sum (across all countries) for all years.

I'm just wondering how something like this could be modelled.

Countries Table

```
Year Country Score
2022 US      500
2021 China   100
2022 UK      200
2019 UK      150
2019 US      300
```

Totals Table

```
Year Country       Score DataCaptured(%)
2019 All Countries 1000  95
2020 All Countries 2000  89
2021 All Countries 4000  89
2022 All Countries 6000  97
```

I've made a start. The countries table acts as a "fact" table. I've created a separated dimension table `[countryID, country]` and replaced countries in the Countries table with the IDs. I've also created a Year table `[YearID, Year]` and replaced years in the Countries table with IDs.

However, I'm not sure how to bring the Totals table into the mix. I would need to link it with the other table based on the Year column. Does it make sense to replace the year with an ID and link it to the Years table?

Comment: I assume you mean star schema, not start schema? What does “DataCaptured(%)” signify? The grain of your initial fact table is “by country by year” so you can’t incorporate your the data in your second table into this fact as you second table has a grain of just year

Comment: Yes meant star schema, or snowflake. It's actually part of an assignment, to load the two files into PowerBI and model as a snowflake schema. I was under the impression that the "Totals" table should be a dimension of the "Countries" table. Regarding data capture, I believe data from "Totals" was collected by other means, and so data wasn't captured for every country.

Comment: @NickW this is part of an assignment and I'm thinking it's just not been thought through very well. I think the lecturer is expecting us to join the Totals table on to the Countries table. Only way I can think to do this is to join the Totals table on to a Year dimension table (which is joined to the Countries fact table).